# How to calculate permutations with limited repetitions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, optimization, permutations, discrete-optimization, operations-research

I have $246$ appointments, that can be scheduled in only $10$ timeslots.
However, $5$ time slots can take up to $30$ ($s_1$) appointments, and the other $5$ can take up to $20$ ($s_2$) appointments.

How to calculate the Permutations with limited repetitions of this problem:

$$n=10, r=246, s_1=30\text{ and }s_2=20$$

What if we simplified the problem to:

$$n=10, r=246, s= 30\text{ for all slots}$$

If the $246$ are variables: $x_1, x_2, x_3,\ldots x_{246}$, and the $10$ timeslots are: $y_1,y_2,\ldots y_{10}$

How to write an equation/constraint that limits the possible Permutations to be only the ones that satisfy the limited repetition (max $30$ of each time slot)?

Comment: What is the source of the problem and what have you tried?  Are you studying Combinatorics?

Comment: From patient scheduling, I don't want to use binary variable to allocate patients to timeslots

Answer (score 2):

As a starting hint, consider the development of the following multinomial

$$
\begin{array}{l}
 \left( {s_1  + s_2  + s_3  + s_4  + s_5 } \right)^{246}  =  \\ 
  =  \cdots \; + \underbrace {\left( {s_1 ^1 s_2 ^0 s_3 ^0 s_4 ^0 s_5 ^0 } \right)}_{1st\;app.\;in\,\;slot\;1}
\underbrace {\left( {s_1 ^0 s_2 ^0 s_3 ^0 s_4 ^1 s_5 ^0 } \right)}_{2nd\;app.\;in\,\;slot\;4} \cdots
 \underbrace {\left( {s_1 ^0 s_2 ^1 s_3 ^0 s_4 ^0 s_5 ^0 } \right)}_{246th\;app.\;in\,\;slot\;2} + \; \cdots  =  \\ 
  = \sum\limits_{\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {0\, \le \,k_{\,j} \, \le 30}  \\
   {k_{\,1}  + k_{\,2}  + \, \cdots  + k_{\,5} \, = \,246}  \\
\end{array}} \right.\;} {\left( \begin{array}{c}
 n \\  k_{\,1} ,\,k_{\,2} ,\, \cdots ,\,k_{\,5}  \\ 
 \end{array} \right)s_{\,1} ^{k_{\,1} } s_{\,2} ^{k_{\,2} }  \cdots s_{\,5} ^{k_{\,5} } }  \\ 
 \end{array}
$$

where in the multinomial sum we limit the exponents to be not more than $30$
(*Note:* actually in this case the sum of the five slots could not reach to 246, but take it to be $m$ and just consider the approach)

Then pass to consider
$$
\left( {s_1  + s_2  + s_3  + s_4  + s_5 } \right)^m \left( {r_1  + r_2  + r_3  + r_4  + r_5 } \right)^n
 \quad \left| \begin{array}{l}
 \;m + n = 246 \\ 
 \;0 \le s_j  \le 30 \\ 
 \;0 \le r_j  \le 20 \\ 
 \end{array} \right.
$$

However, since $5 \cdot 30 + 5 \cdot 20 = 250$, you have better to consider the number of ways
to distribute $4$ null-appointments into a filled-up agenda.